# How to remove event one handler from view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

In the following code:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

   events:{
      "click .button":"cancel"
   },

   cancel:function() {
      console.log("do something...");
   },

   onSomeEvent: function() {
     this.$el.undelegate('.button', 'click', this.cancel);   
   }
});
var view = new AppView();
```

I need to undelegate `this.cancel` handler from elements with '`button`' classes. Unfortunately `this.$el.undelegate` in onSomeEvent method doesn't work.

How could I remove that event handler?

Comment: try `this.$el.off('click', '.button', this.cancel);   `

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like:

```
....
onSomeEvent: function() {
    this.delegateEvents(
        _(this.events).omit('click .button')
    );    
}
```

**update:**

do you mean like:

```
this.events[event] = "someEvent";
//call delegateEvents() on the view to re-bind events
this.delegateEvents();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need to subscribe only this.cancel callback instead all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could I add some events to this.events also?

Comment: @Erik see added answer